# Alternative to this code in Java

Tags: java, optimization, coding-style

So I have made some code for my AP Computer Science class but my teacher is asking me to not use char or token in my code. I have this one code in particular that I need an alternative (non char) version for.

```
// returns the first nonzero digit of a string, 0 if no such digit found
    public static int firstDigitOf(String token) {
        for (char ch : token.toCharArray()) {
            if (ch >= '1' && ch <= '9') {
                return ch - '0';
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

So yes please help me. This isn't homework its a part of a LARGE project so entire lines of code would be appreciated in particular.

```
or (char ch : token.toCharArray()) {
```

This is what I have the most trouble with, I just dont know another way to write this.

Comment: A String is made of chars, if you don't want to use chars, you have to not use a String.  Instead you can use a byte[].

Comment: Your code looks perfectly fine though, btw.

Comment: token is just a variable name. Doees he mean you should not convert the input string to a CharArray or use any char based approaches?

Comment: You can do it with a regular expression, but I would not recommend it.  The way you have written it is both efficient and clear.  However, it seems your assignment is not to make good code, but to solve a puzzle.  A regular expression should be able to pull out a single character without you writing a loop or touch individual character values.

Comment: He may want you to use `substring()` and possibly recursion.

Comment: His teacher just wants him to simplify his code. That's how I understood this question.

Comment: Ask your teacher for clarification. Maybe the input should not be a String but an int?

Answer (score 2):

you can use this

```
String token = "helo100s23h04dsd sdksjdksa";
token = token.replaceAll("[^1-9]", "");
 // in this case token value will be -> 1234, and the first none zero digit is 1
 if (token.length() <= 0) {
  // if there is no numbers in token larger than 0
    return 0;
   } else {
   return Character.getNumericValue(token.charAt(0));
 }
```

Comment: You should remove this check I think "token == null". It is useless, no? You would get NPE earlier if it was null, right?

Comment: This would return the integer value 0x31 if the first digit is 1. The original code subtracted '0' to get 1 instead.

Comment: yes, if you noticed it returns the character it self, not its integer value.

Comment: Ok, I've modified the code, so now it returns int (numeric) value of the character.

Answer (score 1):

This will work if the input string is all digits:

```
public static int firstDigitOf(String digits) {
    if (digits.length() == 0)
        return 0;
    int firstDigit = Integer.parseInt(digits.substring(0, 1));
    if (firstDigit > 0)
        return firstDigit;
    return  firstDigitOf(digits.substring(1));
}
```

Iterative version:

```
public static int firstDigitOf(String digits) {
    int firstDigit = 0;
    while (digits.length() != 0) {
        firstDigit = Integer.parseInt(digits.substring(0, 1));
        if (firstDigit > 0)
            break;
        digits = digits.substring(1);
    }
    return  firstDigit;
}
```

If the string might have non-digits, you need to do this:

```
public static int firstDigitOf(String token) {
    if (token.length() == 0)
        return 0;
    try {
        int firstDigit = Integer.parseInt(token.substring(0, 1));
        if (firstDigit > 0 && firstDigit < 10)
            return firstDigit;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    }
    return  firstDigitOf(token.substring(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following:

```
public Integer firstDigitOf(String s) {
    s=s.replaceAll("[^1-9]","");
    return (s.isEmpty())?0:Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0,1));
}
```

Just replace every non-numerical content and give either 0 or first digit.

Comment: This is not right, I think. What if the string is "0001234" ?

Comment: Yes, it says "non-zero" ... *g*

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of overkill, here's a regular expression version. Note that there is no use direct use of char - it is all done with String.

```
  private static Pattern nonZeroDigit = Pattern.compile("[123456789]");

  public static int firstDigitOf(String token) {
    Matcher digitMatcher = nonZeroDigit.matcher(token);
    if (digitMatcher.find()) {
      return Integer.parseInt(digitMatcher.group());
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
```